# Query to get nextval from sequence in Spring JPA while using different databases

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I need a query to get nextval of a sequence even when I change the database (I have Oracle and Postgres)
When I try to use
`@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT nextval('SEQUENCE_USER')")`
it works with Postgres but not in Oracle
Same with
`@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT SEQUENCE_USER.nextval FROM DUAL")`
works with Oracle and not with Postgres
is there some kind of query that can work with both?

Comment: No because it's a native query. So you have write to queries and choose depending on the database.